# What's the meaning of `linkdown` and `onlink' in Linux Route?

Tags: route

When I typed `ip route show`:
[image: ip route show]

What does `linkdown` actually mean?
Sometimes I can still see `onlink`. Also want to know what `onlink` means.

Does it affect the routing priority? For example, the case of two default routes in the picture

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`linkdown` is the status that will show for a route that is in the table and configured to go out through an interface that is in the `DOWN` state. You can see this by running:

```
ip a
```

and looking for the statuses of the interfaces. On my laptop I have wifi on and the Ethernet adapter unplugged so it shows:

```
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

In my routing table I have a number of routes but I can add a couple garbage ones:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.123.0/24 dev enp0s25
sudo ip route add 192.168.124.0/24 dev wlp3s0
```

Then my table will show `linkdown` for the ethernet route:

```
 192.168.123.0/24 dev enp0s25 scope link linkdown 
 192.168.124.0/24 dev wlp3s0 scope link
```

`onlink` means that the routing should "pretend that the nexthop is directly attached to this link, even if it does not match any interface prefix". So we can make a fake one of those in the table too:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.125.0/24 via 192.168.123.111 dev wlp3s0 onlink
```

Which will now show up in the routing table:

```
192.168.123.0/24 dev enp0s25 scope link linkdown 
192.168.124.0/24 dev wlp3s0 scope link 
192.168.125.0/24 via 192.168.123.111 dev wlp3s0 onlink
```

You can even get fancy and have both if you onlink to the down interface:

```
192.168.126.0/24 via 192.168.123.111 dev enp0s25 onlink linkdown
```

Comment: This answer does not metion "Does it affect the routing priority?" It seems that the behavior is controlled by `ignore_routes_with_linkdown` sysctl.

Answer (score 3):

`linkdown` is the status that will show for a route that is in the table and configured to go out through an interface that is in the `DOWN` state.

I'll try to give an example to see what the `onlink` option really does:

You have configured `eth0` (on your machine) with an ip address/mask: 192.168.0.1/24

For some reason, you want to use a gateway on the physical LAN of `eth0` which has an inconsistent configuration. Assume it has an address 10.0.10.1/24, which does not match the 192.168.0.1/24 configuration you gave your own machine.

If you say:

```shell
ip route add default dev eth0 via 10.0.10.1
```

then you will get an error response (network unreachable or something).

Why? Because (strictly speaking) it does not make sense to have a machine 10.0.10.1 on the `eth0` LAN, because you told your computer this LAN's network address is 192.168.0.0/24.

But here it comes: if you add `onlink` to the command, like this:

```shell
ip route add default dev eth0 via 10.0.10.1 onlink
```

then the route is accepted.

But now we come to another question: What does the kernel do if a packet has to routed to this `onlink` gateway?

I checked (by experiment), and this is the result: The kernel sends an arp request on the `eth0` LAN asking "who-has 10.0.10.1", which is the `onlink` gateway you configured. When it receives a response, the kernel has a **MAC address** where it can send its packets to and routing will be performed.

This means: when the gateway's address doesn't match the LAN configuration on your computer (`eth0`), you can force the kernel to use this gateway by adding `onlink` to the statement.

I guess there very rare situations where you have to use this feature.
Situations where you need the onlink option will mostly be a case of poor network design. I don't think the average tunnel setup needs `onlink` either.

Answer taken from [HERE](https://lartc.vger.kernel.narkive.com/XgcjFTGM/aw-onlink-option-for-ip-route)