# What is the meaning of linkdown in docker0 Linux Route

Tags: docker, routing

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579087/whats-the-meaning-of-linkdown-and-onlink-in-linux-route#:%7E:text=linkdown%20is%20the%20status%20that%20will%20show%20for,and%20looking%20for%20the%20statuses%20of%20the%20interfaces.) already, and understand what linkdown means.

However, for the interface of docker0 running on two of my computers, I have two different cases.

**Case 1**
`linkdown` with `DOWN`

```
$ ip link show dev docker0
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b3:23:3f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$ ip route
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

Here, we see that docker0 is indeed down and has the `linkdown` in routing entry.

**Case 2** No `linkdown` while `DOWN`

```
$ ip link show dev docker0
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:77:ed:9f:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ip route
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
```

Why do I have both of these cases? Pinging after setting up a docker container still works?